# AWS Elastic Beanstalk + RDS Connection Issue

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Although my application was working after hours of troubleshooting, coding, and reading docs, I now suddenly can't reproduce a working environment in Elastic Beanstalk which I have connected to a separate RDS instance through configuration environment variables. Any help would be sincerely appreciated. Below are my logs. It looks like it is failing at the CREATE TABLE stage in my bash script which I don't understand because it was literally just working.

```
/var/log/eb-activity.log

  ++ RDS_USERNAME=matt
  ++ export COMPOSER_HOME=/root
  ++ COMPOSER_HOME=/root
  ++ export PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=256M
  ++ PHP_MEMORY_LIMIT=256M
  ++ export PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=60
  ++ PHP_MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=60
  ++ export PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS=Off
  ++ PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS=Off
  ++ export PHP_COMPOSER_OPTIONS=
  ++ PHP_COMPOSER_OPTIONS=
  ++ export PHP_ALLOW_URL_FOPEN=On
  ++ PHP_ALLOW_URL_FOPEN=On
  ++ export PHP_ZLIB_OUTPUT_COMPRESSION=Off
  ++ PHP_ZLIB_OUTPUT_COMPRESSION=Off
  ++ export PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/web
  ++ PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/web
  ++ export PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE=UTC
  ++ PHP_DATE_TIMEZONE=UTC
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
  + EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/var/app/ondeck
  + cd /var/app/ondeck
  + '[' -f composer.json ']'
  + export COMPOSER_HOME=/root
  + COMPOSER_HOME=/root
  + '[' -d vendor ']'
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config optionsettings -n aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini -o composer_options
  + PHP_COMPOSER_OPTIONS=
  + echo 'Found composer.json file. Attempting to install vendors.'
  Found composer.json file. Attempting to install vendors.
  + composer.phar install --no-ansi --no-interaction
  Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
  Loading composer repositories with package information
  Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
  Package operations: 9 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
    - Installing psr/log (dev-master 65f363a): Cloning 65f363ac44 from cache
    - Installing symfony/routing (2.4.x-dev e4ef317): Cloning e4ef317134 from cache
    - Installing symfony/http-foundation (2.4.x-dev 25b49c4): Cloning 25b49c494e from cache
    - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (2.4.x-dev 2b063f8): Cloning 2b063f8cd9 from cache
    - Installing symfony/debug (dev-master ffad875): Cloning ffad875704 from cache
    - Installing symfony/http-kernel (2.4.x-dev eb1ed60): Cloning eb1ed60a4a from cache
    - Installing pimple/pimple (1.1.x-dev 2019c14): Cloning 2019c145fe from cache
    - Installing silex/silex (dev-master dfd5abc): Cloning dfd5abce32 from cache
    - Installing twig/twig (dev-master ae89c88): Cloning ae89c88535 from cache
  symfony/routing suggests installing doctrine/annotations (For using the annotation loader)
  symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/config (For using the all-in-one router or any loader)
  symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/expression-language (For using expression matching)
  symfony/routing suggests installing symfony/yaml (For using the YAML loader)
  symfony/event-dispatcher suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
  symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/browser-kit ()
  symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/class-loader ()
  symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/config ()
  symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/console ()
  symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/dependency-injection ()
  symfony/http-kernel suggests installing symfony/finder ()
  silex/silex suggests installing symfony/browser-kit (>=2.3,<2.5-dev)
  silex/silex suggests installing symfony/css-selector (>=2.3,<2.5-dev)
  silex/silex suggests installing symfony/dom-crawler (>=2.3,<2.5-dev)
  silex/silex suggests installing symfony/form (>=2.3,<2.5-dev)
  Generating autoload files
[2018-02-15T05:10:10.963Z] INFO  [3465]  - [Application update eb-demo-php-simple-app-v1.1@3/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/12_update_permissions.sh] : Starting activity...
[2018-02-15T05:10:11.760Z] INFO  [3465]  - [Application update eb-demo-php-simple-app-v1.1@3/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook/12_update_permissions.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_user
  + EB_APP_USER=webapp
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_base_dir
  + EB_APP_BASE_DIR=/var/app
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_staging_dir
  + EB_APP_STAGING_DIR=/var/app/ondeck
  ++ /opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container -k app_logs_dir
  + EB_APP_LOGS_DIR=/var/app/support/logs
  + cd /var/app/ondeck
  + chown -R webapp:webapp /var/app
  + chown -R webapp:webapp /var/log/httpd
  + '[' -f app/SymfonyRequirements.php ']'
[2018-02-15T05:10:11.760Z] INFO  [3465]  - [Application update eb-demo-php-simple-app-v1.1@3/AppDeployStage0/AppDeployPreHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre.
[2018-02-15T05:10:11.761Z] INFO  [3465]  - [Application update eb-demo-php-simple-app-v1.1@3/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Starting activity...
[2018-02-15T05:10:12.572Z] INFO  [3465]  - [Application update eb-demo-php-simple-app-v1.1@3/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild] : Starting activity...
[2018-02-15T05:10:12.580Z] INFO  [3465]  - [Application update eb-demo-php-simple-app-v1.1@3/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_tutorials] : Starting activity...
[2018-02-15T05:10:13.258Z] INFO  [3465]  - [Application update eb-demo-php-simple-app-v1.1@3/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_tutorials/Test for Command create-table] : Starting activity...
[2018-02-15T05:10:13.266Z] INFO  [3465]  - [Application update eb-demo-php-simple-app-v1.1@3/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_tutorials/Test for Command create-table] : Completed activity. Result:

  Completed successfully.
[2018-02-15T05:10:13.267Z] INFO  [3465]  - [Application update eb-demo-php-simple-app-v1.1@3/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_tutorials/Command create-table] : Starting activity...
[2018-02-15T05:12:23.193Z] INFO  [3465]  - [Application update eb-demo-php-simple-app-v1.1@3/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_tutorials/Command create-table] : Activity execution failed, because: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mydbinstance.cqplhkqkjgbu.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com' (110)
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)


[2018-02-15T05:12:23.193Z] INFO  [3465]  - [Application update eb-demo-php-simple-app-v1.1@3/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_tutorials/Command create-table] : Activity failed.
[2018-02-15T05:12:23.193Z] INFO  [3465]  - [Application update eb-demo-php-simple-app-v1.1@3/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild/postbuild_0_tutorials] : Activity failed.
[2018-02-15T05:12:23.193Z] INFO  [3465]  - [Application update eb-demo-php-simple-app-v1.1@3/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild/Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild] : Activity failed.
[2018-02-15T05:12:23.234Z] INFO  [3465]  - [Application update eb-demo-php-simple-app-v1.1@3/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPostBuild] : Activity failed.
[2018-02-15T05:12:23.234Z] INFO  [3465]  - [Application update eb-demo-php-simple-app-v1.1@3/AppDeployStage0] : Activity failed.
[2018-02-15T05:12:23.234Z] INFO  [3465]  - [Application update eb-demo-php-simple-app-v1.1@3] : Completed activity. Result:
  Application update - Command CMD-AppDeploy failed
[2018-02-15T05:13:39.397Z] INFO  [3902]  - [CMD-TailLogs] : Starting activity...
[2018-02-15T05:13:39.397Z] INFO  [3902]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Starting activity...
[2018-02-15T05:13:39.397Z] INFO  [3902]  - [CMD-TailLogs/AddonsBefore] : Completed activity.
[2018-02-15T05:13:39.398Z] INFO  [3902]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
     [2018-02-15T05:13:39.398Z] INFO  [3902]  - [CMD-TailLogs/TailLogs/TailLogs] : Starting activity...
```

Comment: Is your database's security group configured to allow incoming requests from your EB instance?

Comment: yes it is. I got this error so I copied my log above -                     [Instance: i-0ba0435f2ec0dd658] Command failed on instance. Return code: 126 Output: /bin/sh: .ebextensions/deployschema.sh: Permission denied. container_command create-table in .ebextensions/database.config failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.

Comment: Where is the best resource to learn to connect your Elastic Beanstalk environment to your integrated RDS environment? Nothing in documentation or samples is working.

Comment: Can you show your `.ebextensions/deployschema.sh` and `.ebextensions/database.config` files? There shouldn't be anything needed to connect EB and RDS other than the five environment variables (`RDS_HOSTNAME`, `RDS_DB_NAME`, `RDS_PASSWORD`, `RDS_USERNAME`, and `RDS_PORT`) and configuring the security groups correctly.